# Angular 2 No provider for CompilerFactory

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-compiler-cli

I'm getting this error on my Ahead-of-Time compiled application:

```
Error: No provider for CompilerFactory!
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:5050/app.js:2413:26)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:5050/app.js:2612:19)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:5050/app.js:2651:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:5050/app.js:4637:22)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:5050/app.js:4671:28)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:5050/app.js:4625:28)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:5050/app.js:4385:24)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:5050/app.js:10924:64)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:5050/app.js:10910:24)
    at http://localhost:5050/app.js:64873:22
```

Application is built using NGC to generate the .ngfactory files, then TSC with a different `main` file to get the JS, then rollup w/Babel to complete the build.  Following [this](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/) guide fairly closely.

Here's my `main.prod.ts`:

```
import "reflect-metadata";

import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowser } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from "./app.module.ngfactory";

enableProdMode();

platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(<any> AppModuleNgFactory)
```

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm running into same issue.

Comment: I was able to fix it using solution from @nrobinaubertin. Replace `bootstrapModule` with `bootstrapModuleFactory` and you're good to go. (no `<any>` cast is necessary anymore)

Answer (score 2):

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModule(<any> AppModuleNgFactory)
```

Should be

```
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory)
```

Comment: That's just a TS typecast to allow it to compile (a separate issue), but has no bearing on the runtime error.

Comment: I feel like I'm not as literate in Angular as you but the main ts file of your guide uses this syntax.  
If you're only doing aot (and no jit), I don't see why you would need two main files.
Could you post your other main file and your package.json ?

Comment: Yeah, the important part is `bootstrapModuleFactory` instead of `bootstrapModule`.